# I get this Error again n again

Tags: php, mysql

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\ad10.php on line 22

```
<?php

$c=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Connection Error");

mysql_select_db("staff") or die("database error");

$q=mysql_query("select * from teachers");

echo "<table border=1>

<th>Number</th>

<th>Name</th>

<th>Shift</th>

<th>Class</th>

<th>Update</th>

<th>Remove</th>";

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($q))

{

?>

<tr>

    <td><? echo $row['Name'];?></td>

    <td><? echo $row['Shift'];?></td>

    <td><? echo $row['Class'];?></td>

</tr>

<?

}

?>

    </table>
```

can anyone please notify the problem with the code.....

Comment: insert your connection in select db,
mysql_select_db("staff",$c) or die("database error");

Answer (score 1):

You don't have short tags enabled so your closing curly, `}`, inside `<? ?>` doesn't close the `while` loop.

```
<?php
$c=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Connection Error");
mysql_select_db("staff") or die("database error");
$q=mysql_query("select * from teachers");
echo "<table border=1>
<th>Number</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Shift</th>
<th>Class</th>
<th>Update</th>
<th>Remove</th>";
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['Name'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Shift'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Class'];?></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>    
</table>
```

Actually after writing this noticed `name`, `shift`, and `class` are in short tags so they also wouldn't have been outputted so maybe this is wrong?

Comment: If short tags are not enabled on OP's server, then yes; that would also cause an unexpected end of file parse error.

Comment: @Sheikh Salman Aziz, please let us know if this resolved the issue or not.